# Matches same value decimal numbers to push in to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

i have a Srings inside of array

```
var QNo = ["1.1","1.2","1.3","2.1","2.2","3.1","3.2","3.3","4.1","4.2"];
```

Need to change **QNo** in array of objects with matching decimals like this

```
var result = [["1.1","1.2","1.3"],["2.1","2.2"],["3.1","3.2","3.3"],["4.1","4.2"]];
```

i hv tried this kind of code

```
for (var j = 0; j < QNo.length ; j++) {
     if ( QNo[j].match(/.*(?=\.)/g) ) {
      result.push(QNo[j]);
     }
}
```

After the Match i don't get any idea to push decimals values as object

Comment: ok, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I Hv tried match(/.*(?=\.)/g) to find the decimal's and i got stucked after this.

Comment: Add the code that you wrote, and not only the regex. Did you write any kind of loop to go over all the values?

Comment: bzw, your result is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to go over all the items in the array and group them by their int value using an `object` where each item will go into the relevant `key` in that object (the key is based on the int value):

```js
var QNo = ["1.1","1.2","1.3","2.1","2.2","3.1","3.2","3.3","4.1","4.2"];
var reduced = QNo.reduce((res, item) => {
  if (res.hasOwnProperty(parseInt(item))) {
    res[parseInt(item)].push(item)
  } else {
    res[parseInt(item)] = [item]
  }
  return res;
}, {});
console.log(reduced);
console.log(Object.values(reduced));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the left part of the splitted value and check if the last value is in the same group -- then push the value to the group. If not, then build a new group.

```js
var qNo = ["1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "2.1", "2.2", "3.1", "3.2", "3.3", "4.1", "4.2"],
    result = qNo.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        function left(a) { return (a || '').split('.')[0]; }
        if (left(a) === left(aa[i - 1])) {
            r[r.length - 1].push(a);
        } else {
            r.push([a]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For unsorted values, you could use a hash table and sort the result later.

```js
var qNo = ["1.1", "3.1", "1.2", "1.3", "2.1", "3.2", "3.3", "4.1", "2.2", "4.2"],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = qNo.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        function left(a) { return (a || '').split('.')[0]; }
        var key = left(a);
        if (!hash[key]) {
            hash[key] = [];
            r.push(hash[key]);
        }
        hash[key].push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Note that the solution will work only if the strings are sorted... otherwise it will not work. I know it was not in the question (and the original input is sorted) but I'm not sure it's a good practice to rely on that :)